# inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+2028)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

When trying to use the inputenc package to enable utf8 characters in my document, I get the error `inputenc Error: Unicode char   (U+2028) not set up for use with LaTeX`. It is triggered by a display formula inside a quote environment. E.g., the following sample already triggers it:

---

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \begin{document}
   \begin{quote}
     blah: \[ blah \]
   \end{quote}
 \end{document}
```

---

I thought about `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2028}{}` and that actually seems to work (defining it as `\\` produced underfull hboxes), but this feels a bit dodgy; shouldn't this just work out-of-the-box? I'm using the latest version of TeXLive 2016.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why have you got line separator in your source?? :-) but anyway this is expected: Unicode has tens of thousands of characters, inputenc does not define tex code for them all, you just need to use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` for any additional ones that you need. So your suggestion of

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2028}{}
```

is good, or perhaps

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2028}{\linebreak}
```

depending on the intended meaning of the character. But really such a control character shouldn't be in a tex source at all.

---

If you paste `blah: \[ blah \]` into

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

Then you will see the following, showing that you have the control character between `:` and `\[`

```
  U+000a LINE FEED (LF)     &NewLine;
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B     b
  U+006c LATIN SMALL LETTER L     l
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H     h
  U+003a COLON     &colon; \mathcolon :
% U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
  U+005c REVERSE SOLIDUS     &bsol; \backslash \textbackslash
  U+005b LEFT SQUARE BRACKET     &lsqb; &lbrack; \lbrack [
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B     b
  U+006c LATIN SMALL LETTER L     l
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H     h
  U+0020 SPACE     \space
  U+005c REVERSE SOLIDUS     &bsol; \backslash \textbackslash
  U+005d RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET     &rsqb; &rbrack; \rbrack ]
  U+000a LINE FEED (LF)     &NewLine;
```

Comment: Thanks, `\linebreak` is probably even better (2028 is a linebreak), however, if you do that then the output is different from the one without inputenc and that can't be right. The really weird thing is though that I do not have that character anywhere in my source so it must be generated internally by the combination of `quote` and `\[` That's also why I think this is a bug.

Comment: @HayoBaan: You do have the character in your source, I can see it in a suitable editor if I copy your example. It is between the colon and the [. Delete this part of the text and retype and you will see that the error is gone.

Comment: @HayoBaan as Ulrike says you do have the control character after the colon.

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Now, how I got that character in my code (even when I created the short example, albeit from the original) is another matter, but the mystery is solved. Many thanks!